# How to display my own map in MKMapView?

Tags: iphone, xcode, dictionary, mkmapview, photo

i have a small map of a town, i want to place it into the google map, any idea how to do it ?
i am doing so because i need google map to point out user current location.

Comment: Is your custom map in KML format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout the TileMap example code from Apple

Comment: its session 127 @ WWDC2010 sessions (you need a payed dev-account for accessing them).

Comment: You can also get it from their sample code pages. Don't know if you need to have a paid account to get there, but since you need one to deploy to your device surely you'd be wasting your time trying to develop without one.

Comment: can somebody share the TileMap apple example?
I can't find it on Apple developer web.

Answer (score -2):

To display a custom map in MKMapView your custom map needs to be in [Keyhole Markup Language (KML)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyhole_Markup_Language). KML is a file format used to display geographic data in an Earth browser such as Google Earth, Google Maps, and Google Maps for mobile. The file can include custom images and annotations.

- [KML Documentation Introduction](http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/)
- [Google Earth](http://www.google.com/earth/index.html)
- [KML Tutorial](http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kml_tut.html) I would follow this tutorial before working on your app. It will give you a better overview of what is possible.
- iOS sample code [KMLViewer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/KMLViewer/Introduction/Intro.html)

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/KMLViewer/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Not true. KML is one way of displaying data on top of a map, but you can display image tiles without ever touching KML. So while data *can* be in KML it does not *need* to be.