# How to preload MKMapView with map data?

Tags: mkmapview

I don't want to assume that a user has Internet access for my app, for various reasons.
In fact it is likely they 30% of the time, they will have neither wifi nor 3G.
So...
How can I preload map data into an MKMapView?
If this is possible, are there copyright issues?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no way to force MKMapView to preload tiles (at least as of iOS 7.0.4).

Answer (score 1):

Start by searching StackOverflow for similar questions

[How to display my own map in MKMapView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691925/how-to-display-my-own-map-in-mkmapview)

The basic point is you need to provide your own data in the form of map tiles. Or checkout CloudMade. The Google data in MKMapview can't be pre-cached and embedded in an app.